# When storing binary data in MongoDB, is it stored as binary or base64 internally

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following class (C#)

```
{
    byte[] somedata;
}
```

Within MongoDB, is it stored in binary form, or is it stored as Base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a (Java) class with the following fields:

```
private String interactionInstanceId;
private String interactionId;
private String messageId;
private byte content[];
```

The `byte content[]` field is saved as `{ "$binary": "<bindata>", "$type": "00"}` in the collection.
I assume that C# is not different

`<bindata>` is "the base64 representation of a binary string", according to this: [BSON Data Types and Associated Representations - Binary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#binary)

I hope this helps

Comment: ok, so that means moving binary in and out of mongo goes through a base64 conversion I guess. Not ideal for performance and space.

Comment: @Thomas - I agree, it is probably not ideal, and that is why you should prefer using GridFS (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) for storing files (in case your byte array is representing a file). GirdFS also supports using Streams (at least in the Java driver), so that is another plus.   
That said, what are you using the byte array for?

Comment: It's to store profile photos, so they're not super large. What I wanted is the ability to deal with data in a single place; but I guess gridfs is probably a smarter choice

Comment: If you are not dealing with large data, maybe byte array is not that bad, especially if it is a single profile picture and you are not retrieving more than one or just a few at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to @ArielGro's answer, AFAICT MongoDB stores binary data in binary form. Although [the MongoDB doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.Binary) mentions Base64 strings I think that's solely about logical structure of the data (described in the form of JSON document). Based on the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) and the fact that MongoDB stores data in BSON, I believe that MongoDB stores binary data in binary form.

That's not to say that *large amounts* of binary data should be stored directly in MongoDB documents. But for small-ish amounts of data, I think it's reasonable.

Comment: Specifically, `binary ::= int32 subtype (byte*)` where first store an int32 with the length and then the bytes as BSON specification. The base64 representation is the extension to the JSON as it can't contain binary data, so it gets converted if you retrieve it as a JSON.